# How to remove auto tag (<ul> & <li>) from g:renderErrors Grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I am displaying custom error in **GSP** page. Using `<g:renderErrors>`, the message displayed inside the `<ul><li>---</li></ul>` tag automatically. But I dont want to do that. I want to display plain message.
**Code :**

```
<td><input type="password"name="userPassword"/></td>
<td>
<g:hasErrors bean="${loginValidation}" field="userPassword">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${loginValidation}"  field="userPassword"/>
</g:hasErrors>
</td>
```

**Snap :**
[image]

How to remove bullet from the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..,.

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${loginValidation}" field="userPassword">
    <g:fieldError bean="${loginValidation}" field="userPassword"/>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer from here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/eachError.html)

```
<g:eachError var="error">
    <g:message error="${error}"/>
</g:eachError>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: renderError has an attribute **as** which may have two values _list_ or _xml_ . By default it is _list_. **renderError** uses looping internally. [Refer from here](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/renderErrors.html)